# Hello on terminal not run when importing

Tags: python-3.x

Tests and the **strange behaviour**: running at command CLI but not as file.

---

**test1.py**. Script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print ("\nHello test1!\n\n")
```

It is fine, all running:

1. [✔] at `python3` command CLI, by copy/paste script.
2. [✔] using `python3 test1.py`
3. [✔] using `chmod 777 test1.py; ./test1.py`

**test2.py**. Script supplied by [chevron's guide](https://github.com/noahmorrison/chevron):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import chevron

chevron.render('Hello, {{ mustache }}!', {'mustache': 'TEST2'})
```

It is fine only by first mode:

1. [✔] at `python3` command CLI, by copy/paste script.
2. [empty output!] using `python3 test2.py`
3. [empty output!] using `chmod 777 test2.py; ./test2.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`chevron.render` returns a string](https://github.com/noahmorrison/chevron/blob/5e1c12827b7fc3db30cb3b24cae9a7ee3092822b/chevron/renderer.py#L185). When not in REPL mode, Python only prints things when asked to:

```
print(chevron.render('Hello, {{ mustache }}!', {'mustache': 'TEST2'}))
```

Comment: Oops... I was blind, thanks to see. Another typical and shameful   [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250659/205446) for my account  :-)